# How to insert dynamic php code into article retrieved from MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent the past 2 days trying to figure this out and came to a conclusion that eval() should not be used due to security issues.

My situation: I have an article stored in MYSQL database in plain text and i would like to add a dropdown menu in the middle of the article as the article is being displayed on the website. This drop down would need to be populated from a database also and the records change everyday thus the need to be dynamic. I would also like to add the code for ad's to certain places within the article.

What is the preferred way?

Comment: how do define in which place a dropdown or ad's markup should be putted within article?

Comment: That is what i'm trying to figure out. What would be the best way to insert the code once i retrieve it from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add to the article a keyword (for example : `{dropdown}`) who triggers the dropdown, then use `str_replace()` to replace `{dropdown}` by your dropdown code :

```
<?php
$article = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. {dropdown} Aliquam tincidunt leo non elementum.';

$dropdownCode = "Here's the dropdown code.";

$article = str_replace('{dropdown}', $dropdownCode, $article);

print $article;

/* Output : 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Here's the dropdown code. Aliquam tincidunt leo non elementum. 
*/
```

Comment: what is I need to insert multiple codes in the article? do i use str_replace() for all of them or maybe create a function for each of them?

Comment: @Boki_LV If you must use several **different** codes, you can create several triggers (`{dropdown1}`, `{dropdown2}`, ...) then use several times `str_replace()` for each of the triggers.